# npm module "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js, npm-publish

I'm building component library using NextJS. The project works fine. However, after I publish my project to npm and import it as a module I get the following error:

[image]

I found a [partial workaround](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules), but it doesn't work that well. The first snippet below, allows the package to work in other repos (can be imported, files accessible, etc.) but when I try to build or run dev to view my components the error above appears. The second code snippet below has the opposite effect (package broken, but local builds succeed)

###### npm package works -- but local builds fail (see screenshot above)

```js
// next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**or...**

###### npm package does not work -- but local builds succeed.

```js
// next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@ellipsis-org/component-library'
]); // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true
};
module.exports = withTM({ nextConfig });
```

---

**HelloWorld Component**

```js
import { styled, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';

const HelloWorld = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Typography variant="caption">HelloWorld</Typography>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default HelloWorld;

const Wrapper = styled('div')`
  border: 1px solid red;
`;
```

Would love some help with this ... it's pretty unfamiliar ground for me.

Comment: Is that the `next.config.js` file for the component library or the app where you're trying to use the component library?

Comment: it's from within the component library itself. I've been reimporting the package back into the library (itself) to see if it works. Maybe thats not a good idea but I don't know another way to quickly test that it works as a package.

Comment: The `next-transpile-modules` solution is what you would do in the app that consumes the component library (assuming it's also a Next.js app), not in the library itself. You either have to transpile beforehand and publish your library, or transpile the library when used in the app.

Comment: interesting, though i wonder, it seems like it introduces a bit of maintenance. How is NextJS able to import other packages without me having to transpile them? Wouldn't it be ideal if i could just import my custom packages _without_ having to also add them to the `next-transpile-modules`? - Any idea why thats the case?

Comment: Since Next.js 12, you should be able to import and use ESM libraries as long as they have `"type": "module"` in their `package.json` by default. See https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#es-modules-support and https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#es-modules-support-and-url-imports.